# Add multiple CHECK constraints on one column depending on the values of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Given a table with two columns col1 and col2, how can I use the Oracle CHECK constraint to ensure that what is allowed in col2 depends on the corresponding col1 value.

Specifically,

- if col1 has A, then corresponding col2 value must be less than 50;
- if col1 has B, then corresponding col2 value must be less than 100;
- and if col1 has C, then corresponding col2 value must be less than 150.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a case statement, eg. something like:

```
create table test1 (col1 varchar2(2),
                    col2 number);

alter table test1 add constraint test1_chk check (col2 < case when col1 = 'A' then 50
                                                              when col1 = 'B' then 100
                                                              when col1 = 'C' then 150
                                                              else col2 + 1
                                                         end);

insert into test1 values ('A', 49);
insert into test1 values ('A', 50);
insert into test1 values ('B', 99);
insert into test1 values ('B', 100);
insert into test1 values ('C', 149);
insert into test1 values ('C', 150);
insert into test1 values ('D', 5000);

commit;
```

Output:

```
1 row created.

insert into test1 values ('A', 50)
Error at line 2
ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_USER.TEST1_CHK) violated

1 row created.

insert into test1 values ('B', 100)
Error at line 4
ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_USER.TEST1_CHK) violated

1 row created.

insert into test1 values ('C', 150)
Error at line 6
ORA-02290: check constraint (MY_USER.TEST1_CHK) violated

1 row created.

Commit complete.
```

Answer (score 2):

add `check constraint` using `case` statement

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
  col1 varchar(10),
  col2 numeric(4),
  CONSTRAINT check_cols_ctsr
  CHECK (CASE WHEN col1='A' THEN col2 ELSE 1 END <50 AND 
         CASE WHEN col1='B' THEN col2 ELSE 1 END <100 AND 
         CASE WHEN col1='C' THEN col2 ELSE 1 END <150)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE MYDEPT (DEPT INT PRIMARY KEY CHECK(DEPT IN(10,20,30,40)),DEPTNAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'NOT GIVEN'
 CHECK(DEPTNAME=UPPER(DEPTNAME)) UNIQUE NOT NULL, DEPTLOC VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'NOT GIVEN' 
 CONSTRAINT CHECK_DEPT CHECK (DEPTLOC IN ('BBSR','HYD','MUMBAI','PUNE')), CONSTRAINT CHECK_DEPT1 CHECK (DEPTLOC=UPPER(DEPTLOC)))

To add multiple check constraints in a single column, you have to define multiple user defined check constraints as shown above.